# Non-preset runtime transformations

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime

What is the basic approach to give class a new method on runtime (may be not a method per se but an ability to change field values)? Say, I'm modeling the evolution of species and I need an animal to develop a new feature or acquire a new move that it didn't have before.

My first impulse was to write a method that takes another method as an argument so that the latter would be responsible for the stuff that is not defined within class. But Java doesn't support methods as arguments. I wonder then, is there a common way to accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try to use Function as param

Comment: method params go by the name of [lambdas](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp) in Java.

Comment: Java does support methods as values (and hence as arguments), see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html